# ansible : pushing results to a database with a webhook

Tags: ansible

I want to put my ansible results into a database.

I made a simple php webpage that listen for post data : server name, number of updates to install, etc and write it into a mysql database for later use (with grafana)

---> How can I make my ansible-playbook make a http post from the ansible server to save results?

I have seen uri but looks to work from the client. Maybe callback plugin but did not seen a simple http plugin.

an idea??

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if you have considered something like [ARA](https://ara.recordsansible.org/), which was written to put the results of Ansible runs into a database (and provide a UI for querying that information).

Answer (score 0):

You should try [ansible-cmdb](https://github.com/fboender/ansible-cmdb) for this. It has options to store Ansible's output in the form of HTML, CSV, SQL, etc.

Option `--template sql` is available which is helpful in exporting to MySQL Database.